# Boost::shared_ptr and its attributes

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

Under the boost library I often see objects like

```
   boost::shared_ptr<std::string>
   boost:shared_ptr<tcp_connection>

   boost::enable_shared_from_this<tcp_connection>
```

What type of attributes does shared_ptr has?  and how does enable_shared_from_this relate to shared_ptr?

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#Synopsis) you find the attributes.

You'd inherit from `boost::enable_shared_from_this<T>` if you want to be able to get a `boost::shared_ptr<T>` using `this->shared_from_this()` or, in general, `ptr->shared_from_this()`. It basically embeds the reference count into `T` rather than allocating it in a separate location.